# Why is my wood screw getting stuck in my bowl when turning with my lathe chuck?

Tags: turning, lathe-chuck

I'm starting wood turning, I'm currently doing my second bowl.  For some reason, my wood screw is getting stuck in my bowl. (both times)  Whenever I try to remove my bowl, it simply does not move.  It seems to spin, as if the wooden threads were stripped.

To remove the screw, I have to cut the inside of the bowl with the screw in.  Once I'm far enough, the screw can get lose with residual wood around; which I remove manually. (With manual tools, pliers, chisels, etc)

Here's the chuck that I'm using.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you turning the bowl the correct way to unthread it? Often on  lathe accessories (and on other power tools) the thread is reversed so that the spinning of the lathe doesn't undo the screw

Comment: I'm pretty sure, but I will make sure to double check next time.

Comment: If the reverse threading isn't the issue it might be due to the grain of the wood, whether the screw went into end grain or close to it screw threads aren't held strongly.